# Why is the User created during linux installation not the root user?

Tags: linux, installation, linux-mint, root

Whilst I was installing Linux Mint... I created a user profile.. then after the installation was complete I tried installing NASM but after executing the make install command it failed to create directory and a error message "failed to create directory... Permission denied" appeared.

I logged out of my account typed in root in the login screen and the system booted into the root user...after this the make install command worked and the installation was successful.
So why wasn't the user created during install not the root user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's generally considered a bad idea to run everything as Root.  Since Mint is aimed at end-users and to be "easy to use", they decide this for you.

- [Why is it bad to run as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-run-as-root)
- [Why is it a bad idea to run as root?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52268/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-run-as-root)
- [Is running Supervisor as root a bad idea for security reasons?](https://serverfault.com/questions/455829/is-running-supervisor-as-root-a-bad-idea-for-security-reasons)

Comment: Oww. Thanks. Well is there any way to change that ? Or do I have to always log into the root to make changes to the system ?

Answer (score 1):

To become `root` temporarily and execute commands with higher privileges, you should use the [**`sudo`**](http://www.sudo.ws/) command. In Ubuntu and Mint, the access to the `sudo` command is restricted on a group-membership basis. Usually, your default user should be member of the `admin` (pre-12.04) or `sudo` (since 12.04) group. You can check the group membership with the following command on the console:

```
grep sudo /etc/group
```

or

```
grep admin /etc/group
```

If the resulting line contains your user name, you should be able to use `sudo` without further modifications.

Important: don't use "plain" `sudo` to run GUI applications as root. To run GUI applications, use the `gksudo` or `kdesudo` command (or `sudo -H`).